# SharePoint 2010 change list permission

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list contained in an SPWeb and when the web is provisioned an event receiver change the list permissions by using this code:

```
[...]
SPList theList = web.Lists[listName];
theList.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
SPGroup group = web.Groups["MyGroup"];
SPRoleAssignment ra = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
SPRoleDefinition roleDef = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
ra.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDef);
list.RoleAssignments.Add(ra);
list.Update();
```

Later in the workflow I need to change the permission for the group to be Reader instead of Contributor. I have used the following code

```
SPList theList = web.Lists[listName];
foreach (SPRoleAssignment assignment in theList.RoleAssignments) {
    if (assignment.Member.Name == "MyGroup") {
        assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.RemoveAll();
        SPRoleDefinition rda = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
        assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(rda);
    }
}
```

However this code is not working and does not change the permission on the list.

Could anybody help on understanding which is the right method to change permission for an existing principal?

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing a theList.Update() after your foreach?

Comment: LOL. So much time trying to understand why and.... Thank you very much for the suggestion. If you write it as an answer I can mark it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `theList.Update()` after your foreach statement.